# Storing qbinom for loop result into vector

Tags: r

I can't figure this out, hope someone can help!

What I'm trying to do is to generate a vector from a for loop I have which uses a qbinom() function to calculate the median from a list of different binomial p parameters. I tried copying the code for vector storage from for loops by the letter from a number of examples on line, but none of them uses qbinom as a task. I think the problem lies in how the output from qbinom is inputted into a vector by R. If I didn't need to use qbinom(), I can form a vector just fine using any other action.

I have:

```
list.of.p.parameter <- c(0.32, 0.32, 0.30, 0.24, 0.29, 0.28, 0.25, 0.29, 0.32, 0.27)                             

    for (i in list.of.p.parameter){
  my_vector <-vector(mode="numeric", length=length(list.of.p.parameter))
  median.binom <- qbinom(0.5,5000,i)
  my_vector[i] <- median.binom
  print(my_vector)
}
```

My output ends up like this:

```
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But if I make no effort to be efficient and not try to store my output as a vector, my for loop works fine even with qbinom():

```
for (i in list.of.p.parameter){
  median.binom <- qbinom(0.5,5000,i)
    print(median.binom)
}
```

Result:

```
> for (i in list.of.p.parameter){
+   median.binom <- qbinom(0.5,5000,i)
+     print(median.binom)
+ }
[1] 1600
[1] 1600
[1] 1500
[1] 1200
[1] 1450
[1] 1400
[1] 1250
[1] 1450
[1] 1600
[1] 1350
```

But I actually have a longer list of p parameters, and essentially need to be able to generate a vector so my output is easier to handle.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, here!

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's a vectorized function  so you can just do `qbinom(.5, 5000, list.of.p.parameter)`.

Comment: I feel silly now, thank you!!

Comment: And the reason your “efficient” attempt failed (it isn’t efficient, as @RitchieSacramento has pointed out) is that you reinitialised your result vector at the start of each iteration of the loop.